# How to configure lombok to generate Getters/Setter for static members also when annotated on class

Tags: java, lombok

I have a class for all static members. The number of static members is more than 10 (which may increase with time).

I am using lombok and I want to generate Getters/Setters for all static members using single `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations on class as we do for non-static members.

I know that

> You can also put a @Getter and/or @Setter annotation on a class. In
> that case, it's as if you annotate all the non-static fields in that
> class with the annotation.

I also know that

> We can annotate static fields individually using `@Getter @Setter` to generate Getters/Setters for static fields.

But this looks ugly and I want to make my class look as clean as possible.

Is there any way I can configure / Override @Getter and @Setter annotation so that I can annotate the class and it generate Getters and Setters for all members including static and non-static members, after all, what do those methods do is return the mentioned variable.

To be more precise, I want the following code snippet to generate Getters and Setters for all class variables-

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class myClass {
    private static String d;
    private static SomePojo c;

    private String a;
    private Integer b;
    private SomeClass d;
    
}
```

Comment: Better provide your code. I am not sure what the structure looks like. I cannot picture a setter/getter to a static member.

Comment: Thanks for requesting the edit, however, I was editing the question to provide the code as well. :)

Answer (score 15):

Add `@Getter` to the static member itself.

```
@Getter
private static final String DEFAULT_VAL = "TEST";
```

Comment: I know and that is what I am doing right now. I have already mentioned in the question in `I also know that clause`. But what if I have 100 static fields in a class. it is time consuming to add @Getter to each field. That's my question is about, how can I override or do something so that adding @Getter to the class itself shod do generate getters.

Comment: Then, you do not have to make them static, add them private members, and initiate just static member of the same class to get access to these fields.

Answer (score 2):

For static fields you have to add `@Getter` to the specific field:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Task {
    @Getter
    private static int numberOfTasks;
    @Getter
    private static int taskId;
    private String taskName;
    private Integer executionTime;
}
```